# Can Ansible be used for provisioning operating system to a baremetal booting via network boot?

Tags: operating-system, ansible, build-automation, provisioning

I am trying to provision OS to baremetal server using Ansible via Network/PXE boot. Is this possible?
If yes, please provide the idea/workflow of the process.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Potential scenario would be:

- PXE boot OS
- If not already configured in image, *firstboot.sh* script configures Ansible
- Use [ansible-pull](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-pull.html)

FWIW, below is firstboot.sh script I use to configure [jails](https://galaxy.ansible.com/vbotka/freebsd_jail) in FreeBSD.

```
#!/bin/sh
env ASSUME_ALWAYS_YES=YES pkg install sudo
env ASSUME_ALWAYS_YES=YES pkg install perl5
env ASSUME_ALWAYS_YES=YES pkg install python27
env ASSUME_ALWAYS_YES=YES pkg install py27-ansible24
pw useradd -n admin -s /bin/sh -m
chown -R admin:admin /home/admin
echo "admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /usr/local/etc/sudoers
```